# Crashing on printing uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

Can anybody tell me why does app crash (xcode 11) on a simple

```
 @IBOutlet weak var TxtTitle: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var BtnSubmit: UIButton!


 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        print(TxtTitle.text)
    }
```

It even crashes on

```
@IBAction func ActionSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
if TxtTitle.text != ""
{
//do something
}

}
```

This is the crash log

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: 
file /Users/apple/Documents/Projects/AfriQP/AfriQPay/PopupControllers/
ProfilePage/PopupTableViewCell.swift, line 45
2019-10-01 15:15:47.054155+0530 AfriQPay[3440:351047] Fatal error: 
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: 
file /Users/apple/Documents/Projects/test1/test1/PopupControllers/ProfilePage/
PopupTableViewCell.swift, line 45
```

It simply crashes even if i try to print or po in console. Why is this happening?

The outlet is connected[image: connection]

[image]

The simulator freezes if i try to type anything on the textbox. Is it that the problem?

Comment: where you called this `if TxtTitle.text != ""`, add some additional info

Comment: ensure once your TxtTitle is connected or not.

Comment: `TxtTitle` is nil

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini It isnt nil, i have give it some value (1312312 on storyboard)

Comment: Did you connect TxtTitle in your storyboard or xib?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It is connected

Comment: @ParthAdroja Storyboard

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of what are the outlets attached to your controller?

Comment: @ParthAdroja edited original question and added the image

Comment: @Zyfe3r - is this possible to attach your project

Comment: How is dequeue the cell?

Comment: Share the code of cellforrowatindex path where you init your cell.

Comment: @ParthAdroja The viewcontroller loads properly, and i cant even type new characters into the text box(the simulator freezes) but as soon as i try to print it or do check condition, it crashes. The crash doesn't happen on cellforrowat , and there is nothing in it other than return cell1

Comment: @Larme         guard let cell1 =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as? PopupTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

Comment: Because at load time textfield value is blank and you are printing value of textfiled. So initially textfiled value is nil that time you have to give optional value like print (textfield.text ?? "")

Comment: @yankitPatel The textfield already has value. (132123 something). Even if i remove the print , it crashes on if condition

Comment: `print(TxtTitle)` to see `TxtTitle` is `nil` as I said.

Comment: Why do I see StackView in InterfaceBuilder? The hierarchy doesn't seem clear. I guess that `BtnSubmit` is nil too? The fact that in InterfaceBuilder we see `cell1`, is strange to me too.

Comment: @Larme the cell1 thing is because of Xcode 11. And NO BtnSubmit is not nil. It works as expected, it wont crash as long as i dont touch the textfield